# Confusion about definition of adjoint functors via triangle identities

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I am learning about adjoint functors, so far I have learned a lot about equivalent definitions of adjoint functors.

The one thing I still can't understand very clearly is the definition of adjoint functors via triangle identities.

This definition says:

Given two functors $F:D \to C$, $G:C \to D$, an adjunction $F \dashv G$ is given by two natural transformations

$η:1_{D} \to GF$

$ϵ:FG\to 1_{C}$

such that the following two triangles commute

[image]

i.e.

$ϵF ∘ Fη = 1_{F}$

$Gϵ ∘ ηG = 1_{G}$

Note: Since the triangle on the left is in the functor category $[D, C]$, and the triangle on the right is in the functor category $[C, D]$, so triangle identities may essentially be re-expressed as the language of morphisms (left/right) inverse in the functors categories.

So can I restate the adjoint functors as follows?

Given two functors $F:D \to C$, $G:C \to D$, an adjunction between F and G ($F \dashv G$ or $G \dashv F$) is given by four natural transformations

$η_{1} : F \to FGF$

$ϵ_{1} : FGF \to F$

$η_{2} : G \to GFG$

$ϵ_{2} : GFG \to G$

such that the following two triangles commute,

[image]

i.e.

$1_{F} = ϵ_{1} ∘ η_{1}$

$1_{G} = ϵ_{2} ∘ η_{2}$

This definition seems more intuitive than the original definition, because we can think of $η_{1}$ as the right inverse of $ϵ_{1}$ and $η_{2}$ as the right inverse of $ϵ_{2}$.

What is the difference between these two definitions?

Is there a relationship between them?

Very thanks.

Comment: There is no reason why $\eta_1$ is of the form $F * \eta$ (see the nLab page for [whiskering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/whiskering)); being of this form is a stronger condition.

Comment: @Fosco Very thank you for your prompt reply. The form F∗η is a special case of horizontal composition of natural transformations, but it still be a natural transformation. For example, in the category $[D,C]$ and $[C,D]$, there may be a lot of functors as objects, natural transformation as morphisms. Can I pick 4 natural transformations in $[D,C]$ and $[C,D]$ which satisfy triangle identities? The result will be F⊣G or G⊣F or 3rd case?

Comment: What I meant is that it is not enough for $\eta_1$ and $\epsilon_1$ to be mutually inverse; they must be induced by whiskering with a specified $\eta : 1 \to GF$, $\epsilon : FG\to 1$. Now, your question might be "if there are those natural transformations, no matter their origin, satisfying the zigzag identities, are $F,G$ adjoint?" The answer is yes :)

Comment: @Fosco After some thinking, I agree with your previous comments. The definition via 4 natural transformations in the question are indeed weaker than adjunction. But what's the meaning of "If there are those natural transformations, no matter their origin, satisfying the zigzag identities, are F,G adjoint? The answer is yes" In general, if there are four natural transformations satisfying the zigzag identities, no matter their form (e.g. F∗η), then there may be three possible results, right? The three possible results are (1) F⊣G (2) G⊣F (3) neither F⊣G nor G⊣F.

Comment: @Fosco I learned adjunction by analogy "equivalent" between categories, such as adjunction ≤ equivalent ≤ isomorphism (Here "≤" means weaker than). The definition via four natural transformations in the question seem to be even more weaker than adjunction. Is there any official name about this definition? Or Is this definition interesting?

Comment: I suspect you can cook up a pair of functors $(F,G)$ with four natural transformations as in the opening post, having no relation of adjointness. I also suspect there is little interest in building this counterexample :) better to learn how to recognise functors that are adjoints!